# Where to find SMTP configuration for mutt on redhat?

Tags: rhel, mutt, smtp

I can already send emails using mutt, but I want to know the IP of the SMTP server that mutt is using, where should I search for this IP ?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, I have the exact same problem. My system has `mutt` installed and running, but I can't find the configs for it anywhere. Google results seem to assume you have a `~/.muttrc` file, but that is not the case for me.

Answer (score 2):

mutt by default does not use SMTP but sendmail. So it will call your sendmail binary and let it handle the rest. The sendmail binary usually comes from original sendmail or Postfix or whatever MTA you have installed.

Comment: Where to find the IP of the server that handles the mail after sending?

Answer (score 1):

/etc/mail/sendmail.cf

**more information**

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-email-mta-sendmail.html

Answer (score 0):

"Where to find the IP of the server that handles the mail after sending?"

As per zhenech's comment that `mutt` uses `sendmail`, I found this page which might (?) help answer that question:

(I'm on CentOS, related to RHEL)

https://sachinsharm.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/setting-up-sendmail-on-centosrhel-6-3/

> 4) Configuration
>
> 4.1) By default sendmail configuration files are located at /etc/mail.
>
> 4.2) By default sendmail listen on local interface i.e 127.0.0.1, check using this command:

```
   # ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i sendmail
   root      3595     1  0 00:20 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: accepting connections
   smmsp     3604     1  0 00:20 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue

   # netstat -an | grep :25 | grep tcp
   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

> 4.3) To configure the sendmail to listen to all interface at the host, just comment the following line in “sendmail.mc”:

```
   # vi /etc/mail/sendmail.mc

     From:
     DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl

     To
     dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
```

Didn't actually help me though, since none of the files that article reference exist on my system, but maybe it will help you or someone else.